# Format of Date Parameter in Oracle BI Reports

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, date-arithmetic

In Oracle BI Publisher, I can't seem to find in what format the date parameters are passed in to the query. For example

```
select * from myTable where the_date = :the_date
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would typically be via the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter, either set in your session or for the whole database. The default in oracle is 'DD-MON-YY'. Of course you may change your query to take it in any format you wish with the to_date conversion function.

Comment: If that works for you, you can hit the Accept on this answer as well. Thx -rew